# Atata Attach to Browser Instance

Tags: c#, google-chrome, atata

I know there is a way in Selenium to launch a browser (at least in Chrome) and later attach to that instance. Can you do the same thing through Atata?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the sample that starts Chrome and then attaches Atata (ChromeDriver instance) to the created Chrome.

```
// Set static or find available port number:
int chromePort = 9222;

// Run Chrome process:
Process chromeProcess = new Process
{
    StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
    {
        FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe",
        Arguments = $"https://demo.atata.io/ --new-window --remote-debugging-port={chromePort} --user-data-dir=C:\\Temp"
    }
};

chromeProcess.Start();

// Create Atata context attached to the Chrome:
AtataContext.Configure()
    .UseChrome()
        .WithOptions(x => x.DebuggerAddress = $"127.0.0.1:{chromePort}")
    .Build();

// Do some actions using Atata:
Go.To<OrdinaryPage>(url: "https://demo.atata.io/products")
    .PageTitle.Should.Contain("Products");

// Clean up (just don't do it exactly like here. Use "using (...)", etc.):
AtataContext.Current.Dispose();
chromeProcess.CloseMainWindow();
chromeProcess.Dispose();
```

The main thing to attach to Chrome is `.UseChrome().WithOptions(x => x.DebuggerAddress = $"127.0.0.1:{chromePort}")`.